# Row position of last match

Tags: excel

[image]

I am wondering what excel methods/functions I can use to return the row position of an input's last match in the data.

For example, Apple should return 8.
Orange should return 9. Watermelon should return 7. Pear should return 5. Pineapple should return 4.

Comment: If I google your question text the first result answers the question.

Comment: @SJR Forgot mentioning this. But without using the array function (ctrl shift enter)

Comment: This is, no doubt, the google result that @SJR is referring to: https://exceljet.net/formula/get-last-match. If it helps, my search terms were "excel last match in a row"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can achieve this, without adding any columns, is with array function (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

The formula is:

> {=MAX(IF(criteria,ROW(rng)-MIN(ROW(rng))+1))}

And you'll get the expected result:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to do this on VBA?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can insert the array formula with vba or you can create a function that does the same thing but with conventional code.

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, here's an alternative that doesn't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=AGGREGATE(14,4,(A1:A9="Apple")*(ROW(A1:A9)-MIN(ROW(A1:A9))+1),1)
```

Info about the AGGREGATE function [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df)